javascript powerBi api copy as visual
Can we implement a "Copy as Visual" feature in our application? This feature would allow users to copy a Power BI API visual report and paste it as an image into their clipboard, enabling them to easily share and embed the report in other applications. in react js
how we can implement it not using Dom as it's not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
